# Как можно создать такое меню в боте телеграм?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Подскажите как можно сделать похожее меню в боте в телеграм?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Учись пользоваться поисковыми системами. Тут помогают с тем, с чем ты не разобрался после изучения и практики.